# How to check numpy arrays are equal

Tags: python, numpy, assert, array-broadcasting

I was doing some exercises in numpy, in particular for broadcasting, but I'm stuck..
Can someone please explain how assert should be used?

```
def fill_0(n):
    return np.zeros(n) -1

def fill_1(n):
    return np.zeros(n) *(-1)

def fill_2(n):
    return - np.ones(n)

def fill_3(n):
    return - np.ones(n) -2

assert fill_0(4) == fill_1(4) == fill_2(4) == fill_3(4)
```

Comment: I just realized that even the broadcasting is wrong haha that's why I needed to check it

Comment: So why is it wrong to use np.all() ?

Comment: I think you're referring to the `np.all` answer I posted and deleted, which was just plain wrong, sorry :/ But there should be ways to do it with `np.all` I think I'm just too tired to post one now :); In any case, @JohnZwinck's answer is nicer

Comment: Maybe assert `np.all(fill_0(4) == fill_1(4) == fill_2(4) == fill_3(4))` works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do it this way:

```
np.testing.assert_array_equal(fill_0(4), fill_1(4))
np.testing.assert_array_equal(fill_0(4), fill_2(4))
np.testing.assert_array_equal(fill_0(4), fill_3(4))
```

This makes it a lot more clear where the failure is (because each pair is a separate line), and it works even if there are NaNs in the data, whereas regular equality comparison would fail (because NaN==NaN is False).

Comment: which is the same as writing `assert np.array_equal()`, right?

Comment: @Zhang_anlan: No.  As per the docs: *"In contrast to the standard usage in numpy, NaNs are compared like numbers, no assertion is raised if both objects have NaNs in the same positions."*